# Problem with z-index in menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, z-index

When you hover over the items in the menu on [this site](http://staging.taskit.nl/) (User Name: `debug`, Password: `debug`), they won't be entirely displayed (there is this jQuery carousel). This is probably some kind of z-index bug, but I can't fix it, could you please help me with this?

I've used this jQuery cycle plugin as you can see in [the code](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/).

Comment: link you've provided requires username/password

Comment: Your site is behind a login...

Comment: sorry i've updated the login details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit css for #slideshow(`<div id="slideshow"> ... </div>`).
Set:

```
#slideshow {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 962px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Worked out for me.